# Java Spring Eclipse Tomcat - RestTemplate, Consume a HTTPS API

Tags: spring, api, tomcat, https, resttemplate

Im using tomcat 8.5 with RestTemplate to consume iFood API, but i always get 500 error.

My localhost is already using a keystore generated file and configured with toncat.
With other api that uses only HTTP im having no problem.
But i cant make the iFood api with HTTPS work.. IF some one can help me.

Note: I can get the token, but when trying to use eventpolling endpoint i just get the error 500.

Comment: 500 means the server encountered an error when trying to handle your request.  Do you have any access to the server logs or similar to see more about the issue?  Have you tried making a similar request via Postman or a similar too to see if that works or if it also does not work, whether additional info is returned with the error.

Comment: I did a test with postman with no error. But when trying on my localhost 500. I configure the https, witch is needed, but when using the event polling error...

Comment: The problem is that when using the endpoint to acquire the token I get it, but in the eventpolling it does not.
The error that im getting is from this line:

ResponseEntity<DadosAPIIfoodPooling[]> response = template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, DadosAPIIfoodPooling[].class);

All the parameters from the response are with the correct name. So im totaly lost

Comment: Who gets the `500` error? The user-agent (browser?) calling your application, or your application's client calling the REST API? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Im getting this error when i try a get request on the api

Comment: can you try the full API call with Postman, passing in the token you got from your application (or from a first call with Postman) ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the comments, but i found the error.
The problem was that in the iFood API endpoint description, it has a char code inside the url.

The exemples use it normaly, calling from Postman no problem, but when using on Tomcat the char code generates a url error, unfortunately, with no feedback or usable error mesage.

Changing the char code to the corresponding character the problem was solved.